# Update UILabel.text with Coordinates

Tags: ios, user-interface, swift3, uilabel, cllocationmanager

I am trying to display two labels in a detail view of master-detail app. I want the first label to display 'restaurant name' and the second label 'users current location'. I have successfully implemented `locationManager' and I get correct current user's coordinates in my console. However, I would like to display the coordinates in the text of the label. I assume that the problem why the following code is that the second  label sets up before the coordinates are received. What would be the best thing to implement it?

```
func configureView() {

//to display label with restaurant name
    if let restaurant = self.restaurant {
        if let label = self.restaurantNameLabel {
            label.text = restaurant.RestaurantName
        }
    }

 //to display label with user's Latitude and Longitude:

    if let label = self.CurrentLocation {
        label.text = "\(currentLocation?.longitude)"
    }  
}
```

I also have didSet methods:

```
var restaurant: Restaurant? {
    didSet {
        self.configureView()
     }
}

var currentLocation: Coordinate? {
    didSet {
        self.configureView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I suggest renaming the `RestaurantName` property in the `Restaurant` class to just `name` and the `UILabel` `CurrentLocation` to `currentLocationLabel`. Secondly, it would be simpler to configure the property's corresponding label in it's respective `didSet` block. Also, I have used `flatMap` - which in the case of `currentLocation` if nil, will return nil - otherwise, the currentLocation will be manipulated and returned by the closure.

```
var restaurant: Restaurant? {
    didSet {
        restaurantNameLabel?.text = restaurant.flatMap { $0.name }
    }
}

var currentLocation: Coordinate? {
    didSet {
        currentLocationLabel?.text = currentLocation.flatMap { "\($0.latitude), \($0.longitude)" }
    }
}
```